# Business Validation side by side with DataAnnotations in layers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

I have a MVC 3 application with a 3 layer approach. My Data layer contains the edmx file and a t4 template which generates my entities with the basic DataAnnotations every time my edmx file changes.

In addition I am making use of following to allow additional validation for existing entity and property. This one allows me to combine the auto generation DataAnnotations with own written annotations.

```
[MetadataType(typeof (PersonMetaData))]
public partial class Person
{
}

public class PersonMetaData
{
    [RegularExpression(@"(\w|\.)+@(\w|\.)+", ErrorMessage = "Email is invalid")] public string Name;
}
```

Going further I found following article http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnModelsAndViewModels/ExtendingTheModelBinderForEnhancedValidation

This allows me to use the existing ASP.NET MVC logic and implement, if needed, an own validation method. The example works for me.

Unfortunately, because I have a 3 layer application and want to validate my entities in the Business logic (and not in the Data layer), I cannot put any call to the Business Logic into the Validate method without creating a circular dependency.

Is there any better approach to combine auto generated DataAnnotations, own validationextensions, validation in the business logic and the IBindingValidatable method?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should keep validation resulting from business logic rules in the business layer, and only include data entry validation in the UI layer.

So for example validating an email address entry, according to some regex belongs in the UI layer, but making sure that email address is unique to your system should be done in the business logic.

I hope this helps.